# Method resolution order in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Consider the following class hierarchy:

- base class Object with a virtual method foo()
- an arbitrary hierarchy with multiple inheritance (virtual and non-virtual); each class is a subtype of Object; some of them override foo(), some don't
- a class X from this hierarchy, not overriding foo()

How to determine which method will be executed upon a call of foo() on an object of class X in C++?

(I'm looking for the algorithm, not any specific case.)

Comment: Guys, he's not asking about a virtual table. He's asking how the compiler chooses which `foo` is called.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no MRO in C++ like Python. If a method is ambiguous, it is a compile-time error. Whether a method is virtual or not doesn't affect it, but virtual *inheritance* will.

---

The algorithm is described in the C++ standard §[class.member.lookup] (10.2). Basically it will find the closest unambiguous implementation in the superclass graph. The algorithm works like this:

1. Suppose you want to look up a function **f** in class **C**.
2. We define a *look-up set* **S(f, C)** being a pair of sets (**Δ**, **Σ**) representing all possibilities.  <sub>(§10.2/3)</sub>

   - The set **Δ** is called the *declaration set*, which is basically all the possible **f**'s.
   - The set **Σ** is called the *subobject set*, which contain the classes that these **f**'s are found.
3. Let **S(f, C)** include all **f** directly defined (or `using`-ed) in **C**, if any <sub>(§10.2/4)</sub>:

   ```
   Δ = {f in C};
   if (Δ != empty)
     Σ = {C};
   else
     Σ = empty;
   S(f, C) = (Δ, Σ);
   ```
4. If **S(f, C)** is empty <sub>(§10.2/5)</sub>,

   - Compute **S(f, B<sub>i</sub>)** where **B<sub>i</sub>** is a base class of **C**, for all *i*.
   - Merge each **S(f, B<sub>i</sub>)** into **S(f, C)** one by one.

     ```
     if (S(f, C) == (empty, empty)) {
       B = base classes of C;
       for (Bi in B)
         S(f, C) = S(f, C) .Merge. S(f, Bi);
     }
     ```
5. Finally the declaration set is returned as the result of name resolution <sub>(§10.2/7)</sub>.

   ```
   return S(f, C).Δ;
   ```
6. The merge between two look-up sets (**Δ<sub>1</sub>**, **Σ<sub>1</sub>**) and (**Δ<sub>2</sub>**, **Σ<sub>2</sub>**) is defined as <sub>(§10.2/6)</sub>:

   - If every class in **Σ<sub>1</sub>** is a base class of at least one class in **Σ<sub>2</sub>**, return (**Δ<sub>2</sub>**, **Σ<sub>2</sub>**).
     (Similar for the reverse.)
   - Else if **Δ<sub>1</sub>** ≠ **Δ<sub>2</sub>**, return (*ambiguous*, **Σ<sub>1</sub>** ∪ **Σ<sub>2</sub>**).
   - Otherwise, return (**Δ<sub>1</sub>**, **Σ<sub>1</sub>** ∪ **Σ<sub>2</sub>**)

     ```
     function Merge ( (Δ1, Σ1), (Δ2, Σ2) ) {

        function IsBaseOf(Σp, Σq) {
          for (B1 in Σp) {
            if (not any(B1 is base of C for (C in Σq)))
              return false;
          }
          return true;
        }

        if      (Σ1 .IsBaseOf. Σ2) return (Δ2, Σ2);
        else if (Σ2 .IsBaseOf. Σ1) return (Δ1, Σ1);
        else {
           Σ = Σ1 union Σ2;
           if (Δ1 != Δ2)
             Δ = ambiguous; 
           else
             Δ = Δ1;
           return (Δ, Σ);
        }
     }
     ```

---

For example <sub>(§10.2/10)</sub>,

```
struct V { int f(); };
struct W { int g(); };
struct B : W, virtual V { int f(); int g(); };
struct C : W, virtual V { };

struct D : B, C {
   void glorp () {
     f();
     g();
   }
};
```

We compute that

```
S(f, D) = S(f, B from D) .Merge. S(f, C from D)
        = ({B::f}, {B from D}) .Merge. S(f, W from C from D) .Merge. S(f, V)
        = ({B::f}, {B from D}) .Merge. empty .Merge. ({V::f}, {V})
        = ({B::f}, {B from D})   // fine, V is a base class of B.
```

and

```
S(g, D) = S(g, B from D) .Merge. S(g, C from D)
        = ({B::g}, {B from D}) .Merge. S(g, W from C from D) .Merge. S(g, V)
        = ({B::g}, {B from D}) .Merge. ({W::g}, {W from C from D}) .Merge. empty
        = (ambiguous, {B from D, W from C from D})  // the W from C is unrelated to B.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description :) That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Some detailed description with code.

[vtable and vptr](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45816-detail-about-how-vptr-and-virtual-table-works/)

[vtable](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/)

[Virtual Functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr139.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `G++` a vtable (*Virtual Method Table*) is used, you can get more specific details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Not sure if every C++ compiler uses the same approach but I would say yes

Answer (score 0):

If a method of a base class is virtual, every call to it through base or derived pointer/reference will call the appropriate method (The one furthest down the inheritance tree). If the method was declared virtual, you can't have it any other way later : declaring it virtual (or not) in derived classes won't change anything.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is basically which is "the appropriate method", which is non-trivial if the inheritance tree is, well, not a tree.
Python has a nice doc on how they do it: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ ; I'm trying to come up with a similar explanation for C++.