# Multiple inheritance specify desired virtual function without redfining it

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know if there is a way to specify that in multiple inheritence, one of the base-classes virtual functions becomes the single virtual definition. They only way I see to do this is by writing an explicit definition of this function in the derived class and explicitly call one of the base classes. This is cumbersome, and I was hoping `using` might help, but it doesn't.

For example, in the below code, I have to define a `C::value` even though I just wish to forward to the class B version. Is there not a simpler way?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    virtual char const * value() const
    { return "A"; }
};

struct B
{
    virtual char const * value() const
    { return "B"; }
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    //using B::value;
    virtual char const * value() const
    { return B::value(); }
};

int main()
{
    C obj;
    cout << obj.value() << endl;

    A * ptr = &obj;
    cout << ptr->value() << endl;
}
```

Some notes:

- in this particular case virtual inheritance of class A is not an option for Class B -- I need a proper construction chain down to the base
- In theory struct B could also be used unrelated to A, but that is not the case here (in case that provides other options)
- `value` may be marked as pure virtual if that somehow helps, but I don't believe it does.
- there are other classes which derive from A but not B
- to be clear, however "func" is called on C, through any type pointer, must result in "B"

I suspect the answer might be "No", but some confirmation would be good. It feels like the language should support this pattern.

Comment: What is the output of the above program?

Comment: Maybe you can add a dummy 'node' to the inheritance tree (e.g. `DummyC` which virtually inherits from `A`, and `C` which inherits from `DummyC` and `B`). Not sure it's possible, but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310910/method-resolution-order-in-c and see if this helps.

Comment: @Bingo, the above program outputs "B" and "B" because I override the function. If you don't do this, just do the `using` declartion you will get "B" and "A".

Comment: @Asaf, that gives me an idea that perhaps just sticking the "value" function in a dummy virtually inherited base class without a constructor. That would probably work.

Comment: @Asaf, well, my idea doesn't work, it still wants a final overrider.

Comment: Just want to know, what if you would like to use both A's value() and B's value() ? If you want to have both the versions then have to introduce another level of inheritence.

Comment: @Jagannath, for the final class only value should ever be present. That is, I will never want to access the other value. It would actually be an error to have two such values defined.

Comment: What I meant is, you are inheriting 2 classes having same method name, now there should be some need to use both variants. If yes, then there would be a need for another level of inheritence. For eg. consider this code http://ideone.com/I30xS

Comment: @Jagannath, no, there is no need to call both. Class B is functioning as a _mixin_ and simply wants to implement the other function. That is, Class B does nothing but implement functionality already defined, it isn't adding a new interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only way I see to do this is by writing an explicit definition of
>   this function in the derived class ..., and I was hoping using might
>   help

`using` keyword in your context is used only to **bring the names into the current scope** (used against name hiding). Assume that your requested feature is already there. Now see the below modified codes:

```
struct A
{
  virtual char const * value() const
  { return "A"; }

  void value (double);  // new function
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
  using B::value;
  void value(int);  // new function
};
```

Suppose we have functions of the same name as `value(int)` in `C` and `value(double)` in `A`. These 2 functions have nothing to do with `virtual value()` and are used with object of `C`.

How will you use `A::value(double)` with `C`'s object ? Naturally you have to do `using A::value;` in body of `C`. Now because of this, as a side effect we have 2 `virtual` function match: `A::value() const` and `B::value() const`!
Which to choose when called with `A*` or `B*` ?

This is only one example, but there can be other problems too. Whatever you have mentioned in your question is the best way to accomplish the correct result. It explicitly says that `C::value() const` is a wrapper around `B::value() const`.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no other way of doing it other than explicit call to the function using the binary scope resolution `operator::`.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple inheritance is so rare, and the cost of writing such a function so trivial, that it's not worth a language feature, and I certainly know of none that provide such functionality.

The only thing `using` affects is visibility, which is not the issue here, so it most certainly cannot be of any help.

Comment: While your note on visiblity is correct, I don't consider multiple inheritence is rare. Indeed if this pattern was supported it might be more common. Additionally, languages like Python and Ruby can do such things, so it can't be discounted outright as "not worth it".

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Why not? Those other languages are utterly irrelevant. "Worth it" is "Worth it for C++ in the C++ Standard Committee's opinion". Where is Ruby or Python mentioned in there? Nowhere. MI is, wisely, avoided by most programmers, and this is an absolutely miniscule drop compared to the ocean of other problems MI suffers and the trivial solution of simply defining a trivial forwarding function.

Comment: IME, mixins are _far_ from rare.

Answer (score -1):

It's always better to have interface methods as non-virtual. The code below would help you in acheiving what you want. But, the output varies. I believe that is what should be.
The code can be found [here](http://ideone.com/I30xS)

**Output:**

B

A

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

struct A 
{ 
    char const* value() const
    {
        return valueImpl();
    }
protected:
    virtual char const * valueImpl() const 
    { return "A"; } 
}; 

struct B 
{ 
    char const* value() const
    {
        return valueImpl();
    }
protected:
    virtual char const * valueImpl() const 
    { return "B"; } 
}; 

class C : public A, public B 
{ 
public:
   using B::value;

}; 

int main() 
{ 
    C obj; 
    cout << obj.value() << endl; 

    A * ptr = &obj; 
    cout << ptr->value() << endl; 
}
```

Comment: I don't want output "B" "A", I want "B" "B", there should be only one `value()` defined and accessible for the resulting object.