# Override virtual function of base classes, which do not share common interface

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
struct B1
{
    virtual void method()=0;
    virtual ~B1(){}
};

struct B2
{
    virtual void method()=0;
    virtual ~B2(){}
};

struct D: B1, B2
{
    virtual void method()
    {
        std::cout << "D::method\n";
    };
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    D d;
    B1 &b1=d;
    B2 &b2=d;
    b1.method();
    b2.method();
    return 0;
}
```

Note, B1 and B2 do not share common interface.

Is it this legal? If yes - in which standard? C++98/03/11 ?

Both, msvc and gcc have compiled it OK.

Previously I thought, that I have to use some common interface for such case (possible virtual inheritence).

Does such situation have some special name?

How it works in details, please? Maybe some ISO references?

Comment: If you explain what leads you to think it's a special case someone may find a good explanation.

Comment: Because in that case, I expect to have two different *independed* inherited virtual functions in D: B1::method and B2::method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is well-formed:  `void D::method()` overrides both `void B1::method()` and `void B2::method()`.

The specification states (C++11 §10.3/2):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides `Base::vf`.

`B1` declares a virtual member function `void B1::method()`.  Class `D` is derived from `B1` and it also declares a member function with the same name (`method`), the same parameter list (no parameters), the same cv-qualification (no qualification) and the same ref-qualifier (no qualification).

Therefore, `void D::method()` overrides `void B1::method()`.

The same logic applies for `void B2::method()` (just substitute `B2` for `B1` in the above explanation), so `void D::method()` overrides both `void B1::method()` and `void B2::method()`.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds as true. I have found simmilar items on C++03 and C++98. But, I am curious, are there some additions in standard to that situation? Maybe some special notes for multiple inheritance?

Comment: Aside from the "and ref-qualifier," I would expect the specification to be the same in C++98 and C++03.

Comment: Great, that's good to know. By the way, just *using* method() *without* overriding it is only allowed for D if D is accessed through base class references/pointers. Compare  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310910/method-resolution-order-in-c/3310948#3310948

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but it's still surprising. The same body of code is implementing two different methods simultaneously, since surely B1::method and B2::method are unrelated.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every surprising thing I've learned about C++... well, I'd have a lot of dollars.

Comment: I hope that would be not suprise for some compiler developer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Overriding was always implicit in the original C++. Let's say you derive from some `Base` class, add a bunch of methods. Then the `Base` class is upgraded by its author to provide a few more methods, some of which are virtual. One of these new methods has the same name, argument list, cv-qualification... as one of your derived class methods. You now override a base class method, not knowing it, and without even a diagnostic in most (all?) IDE.

Answer (score 1):

afaik this is legal in every standart. i'm not sure if it has it's own special name, but it is similar to the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) .

if you override "virtual void method()" in D, then you override both the method in B1 and B2.

**Edit:**

to anwser why you do not have "two different independed inherited virtual functions in D: B1::method and B2::method":

when overriding a method, you can can only specify the function name, return type and parameters, but you can not add signature details about which one you inherit from when overriding.

imagine that it would be possible, then it could look something like this:

```
struct D: B1, B2
{
    virtual void B1::method()
    {
        std::cout << "D::method\n";
    };
    virtual void B2::method()
    {
        std::cout << "D::method\n";
    };
};
```

**but** seeing this, you can already say that there is no possibility to have something like that, because when calling

```
objectD.method()
```

you can not specify which one you are calling. so even if there was a way to overload both, there is still the problem of distinguishing on the function call.

**EDIT:**
"can not specify which one you are calling." refers to, you can not specify whether you want to call a class D overload of B2::method or the B2 method itself. objectD.B2::method will always invoke the B2 (not overloaded) method (which in this case won't compile as B2 has no implementation)

Comment: Thank you, I understood this. I would like to know some more details, because it is a little bit surprising to me.

Comment: @James McNellis wouldn't that only be possible inside a class member? void B1method(){ B1::method } ?

Comment: i see. still they invoke the base class functions regardless of overloading.

Comment: "_imagine that it would be possible, then it could look something like this:_" then you get a function named `B1::method`, and whose qualified name is `D::B1::method`! But in C++ `D::B1` means `B1`! When the **unqualified** name of a function `B1::method`, you know there is a problem. "_so even if there was a way to overload both,_" it would *not* be overloading, as functions have different names: `B1::method` vs `B2::method`! You can try as much as you want, I just don't think you can make this idea work. (But trying is fun. ;)