# Inheritance, hiding functions, and scopes c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I have an inherited class with function A and B. B does something and call A.
Base class also have function A and B. B does the thing in a different way and then call A (the derived class's A).  However in a specific situation I want to call the base class's B. This is done using Base::B(). Then B will call A, my question is, which A will it call? The base one or the inherited one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether A is virtual or not. If virtual the derived version will be called, if not it will be the base version.

Answer (score 0):

You are proposing a generic scenario here, but it's enough to determine that you are referring to the **MRO**, aka **Method Resolution Order**, which is the algorithm ( or the class of algorithms, you can use this acronym to refer to a general topic or a specific single thing ) used to determine which method needs to be called.

How the MRO works in the C++ case it's described in the standard itself, but there is a dedicated tag here on SO named [*method-resolution-order*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-resolution-order) and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310948/2244984) that can give you a broad view about this.